# Reproject multiple vector layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, pyqgis

How can I reproject multiple vector  layers in QGIS? I have a thousand layers (around 100 in each folder) without projection info. All need to be set in WGS84.
I know about the batch Processing tool but they are so many and in different folders. Is there a command or script in python?

Comment: Are you sure they need to be georeferenced, and not simply reprojected/transformed?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our "Focused question/Best answer" model operates. We are not a coding service. All coding questions are expected to contain a good-faith effort to solve the task, with details of the error or other problem encountered. Please [edit] the question to answer the questions: What have you tried? What problem did you encounter?

Comment: What file format is the data in?

Comment: Do you know corner coordinates of each layer? For example, if all are covering the same region, you will know what are the expected orner coordinates in WGS84. If so, gdal_translate utility as a handy option [-a_ullr ulx uly lrx lry] where you can give upper-left x,y and lower-right x,y coordinates and it will project the layer in the right place. You can write a simple bash script to run this on all layers.

Comment: If all that your layers need is a projection definition of WGS 84 so that software like QGIS can display them properly with other layers, there is a Define Projection tool in Processing - Vector General.  It has a batch process option which takes a bit of fiddling with to learn but afterwards works quite well.  If you need to change all your layers from a different coordinate system to WGS 84 then use the Reproject layer tool also in Vector General.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have edited my question.